Aligning Question

how to get the code for this. I tried \begin{align} and it didnt work out. (The arrows aren't needed)

Welcome to TeX SE. Could you add the code you tried to your post? Have you consider a tabular?

I suggest you use an array environment and use the r column type for the 15 data columns. The data columns will all have equal width, given by the width of $-6$.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}    
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\midrule' macro

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{@{} >{$}l<{$} *{14}{r @{,\,}} r @{}}
Old list 
& 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 \\
&-6 &-6 &-6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 \\
\midrule
New list
& 1 & 2 & 3 &  4 &  5 &  6 &  7 &  8 &  9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15  
\end{array}
\]
 
\end{document}


Addendum: If you're willing and able to use LuaLaTeX to compile your document, you could generate the contents of the array environment programmatically, as follows:
\[
\begin{array}{@{} >{$}l<{$} *{14}{r @{,\,}} r @{}}
Old list 
\directlua{for i=1,15 do tex.sprint ("&" .. i+6) end} \\
\directlua{tex.sprint ( string.rep ( "& -6" , 15 ) )} \\
\midrule
New list
\directlua{for i=1,15 do tex.sprint ("&" .. i) end} 
\end{array}
\]

Such a setup may be especially useful if you change your mind and decide that you need, say, only 12 data columns instead of 15, or if you want to change the subtractive constant from 6 to, say, 9.

Remark: If you want a bit more whitespace after the commas, I suggest you replace @{,\,} with @{,\;}. (In math mode, \, inserts 3mu of whitespace (aka "thinspace"), and \; inserts 5mu of whitespace (aka "thickspace"), where 18mu=1\quad.)

Here's my version where the columns are centered without regard of the commas, which gives a more symmetric look.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\[
% let TeX compute the spacings
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
% the comma is printed as zero width
\begingroup\lccode`~=`,\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\makebox[0pt][l]{,}}
\mathcode`,="8000
% now the table to 95% of the available width
\begin{tabular*}{0.95\displaywidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  *{15}{>{$}c<{$}}
}
Old list &
7, & 8, & 9, & 10, & 11, & 12, & 13, & 14, & 15, & 16, & 17, & 18, & 19, & 20, & 21 \\
& -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 & -6 \\
\midrule
New list &
1, & 2, & 3, & 4, & 5, & 6, & 7, & 8, & 9, & 10, & 11, & 12, & 13, & 14, & 15 \\
\end{tabular*}
\]
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}

The trick for the comma is one from my toolbox: the comma is made math active and results in a text comma printed in a zero width box.

